# Unable to run espresso tests for android

Tags: java, android, junit, junit3, android-espresso

I am having some issues setting up/running espresso tests for android.
My TestClass looks like below:-

```
import static com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.util.Log;

import com.sample.rasmus.MainActivity;

public class BasicTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

public BasicTest(String name) {
    super(MainActivity.class);
    Log.v("amtesting","2");
}
 @Override
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
      Log.v("amtesting","5");
    super.setUp();
    Log.v("amtesting","4");
    // Espresso will not launch our activity for us, we must launch it via getActivity().
    getActivity();
  }

public void testSimpleClickAndCheckText(){
    Log.v("amtesting","1");
    onView(withId(com.sample.rasmus.R.id.thebutton)).perform(click());
    onView(withId(com.sample.rasmus.R.id.helloworld)).check(matches(withText("awesome")));
}

protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
    Log.v("amtesting","3");
    super.tearDown();

}

  }
```

AndroidManifest.xml looks like this:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.sample.rasmus.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

<instrumentation
    android:name="com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
    android:targetPackage="com.sample.rasmus" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
</application>

 </manifest>
```

and the run configurations have been updated to use Google In`GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner` as the InstrumentationRunner.

However when I run the tests , it gives me the below on the console:-

- Launching instrumentation android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner on device emulator-5554
- Sending test information to Eclipse
- Test Finished

There is no mention of running tests and the tests dont run. What could I be missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so this is how I finally solved it. I changed the constructor of the test class to below:-

```
public BasicTest() {
  super(MainActivity.class);
 }
```

and it started working. It is kind of strange that this was the reason which kept me busy the whole day.